The element type 'TableRow' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'
Using Flutter/Dart PDF package, I need to create a table.
When I try to enter DataRow, then I get the error: The element type 'TableRow' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'
Please see the TableRow below(both rows). This is where the problem occurs.
Could you please help.
Here is my code below:
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.standard,build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.SizedBox(child: pw.Table(children:[
            TableRow(children: <Widget>[TableCell(child: Container(height: 30,width: 30,child: Text('')))]),
            TableRow(children: <Widget>[TableCell(child: Container(height: 30,width: 30,child: Text('')))])
        ]));
      }));


Try these:
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

void main() {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Table(
          border: pw.TableBorder.all(),
          children: [
        pw.TableRow(
          children: [
            pw.Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              child: pw.Text('Row 1, Cell 1'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        pw.TableRow(
          children: [
            pw.Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              child: pw.Text('Row 2, Cell 1'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}


This solved the problem. Thank you

Glad it was resolved.
